# What is the meaning of the word 'band' in the following terms: broadband, baseband and bandwidth?

Tags: internet, bandwidth, network, terminology

I am interested in the terminology of the following words: baseband, broadband and bandwidth applied in tellecomunications. What is the meaning of the words, how were they formed and what do they mean in the context of modern networks?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

"Band" applies to the range of electromagnetic spectrum used for the transmission.

Broadband uses a broad range (as opposed to narrowband), baseband is a band starting at zero frequency (or close to).

Bandwidth is used for both the spectral width of a band or channel (e.g. "100 MHz") and for the amount of data that can be transported in a given time frame (as in "100 megabytes per second"). The data throughput meaning is borrowed from the original, spectral meaning - partly because they are correlated.

Comment: in wired copper communication can we still talk about 'electromagnetic spectrum' or not? I guess it is only electrical.

Comment: The signal still moves as an electromagnetic wave in and around a copper cable. At high frequencies, you don't get the exact same electrons out of the end of a cable that you'd put in. The signal / wave travels more like sound in air with the electrons just passing on the pulse instead of moving significantly.